# Should i buy a better CPU or GPU?

Tags: hardware

i'm going to buy a new system mainly for blender, and i'd like to know should i spend more money on the GPU or the CPU?

the current 2 setups would be:

i7-5820k (6 cores) + 2*GTX980  (double monitor)

or

i7-6700k (4 cores) + 2*GTX980Ti  (single monitor)

I'm moving from a AMD laptop, so i don't have much experience in which usage is more common

Comment: when you will be rendering your scenes, it will be either GPU or CPU, you don't need two ultra hardware, CPU allows more Ram usage but two GPUs can hold up if they own enough memory. The risk with gpu is to run out of memory during heavy renders while the advantage is to be faster

Comment: My CPU is out performing my GPU by a factor of about 3 - 1 for a particular rendering example (cycles render - high poly - hair particles). That's a 12 core i77800x vs NVIDIA ROG Strix GeForce GTX 1080 TI OC.

Answer (score 1):

Depends a lot on what kind of work you do.
If you use Cycles render engine GPUs are generally faster at rendering, but as stated their biggest limitation is memory and feature availability. Some features can't still be rendered in the GPU and complex scenes can exceed available memory.

If you do a lot of physics simulations, cloths, particles, or animation, you are going to need a good CPU, and for very big or complex scenes that won't fit your available graphics memory you are also going to fall back to CPU for rendering anyway, so go with a beefier CPU option as it can be more versatile.

Personally I would go with better GPU option though, I own a GTX 580+980ti and they are great for rendering. Memory is big enough even for relatively complex scenes these days, and the speed is better than CPU rendering. Also even a mid-range CPU these days can handle most use cases at a reasonably acceptable speeds.
Good GPUs will also help in viewpoint performance and quality, and can additionally be used for gaming, if you are into that sort of thing.