# How fast can a gtx 1080 TI run out of memory?

Tags: gpu

I want to buy a new desktop for Blender and I would like to bet on the graphics card. However, I don’t understand how it renders animations. Is the memory used per frame or per animation as a whole? Also I understand denoising takes a lot of resources as well.

While I’m asking, I read that high frequency in a cpu is better then multiple cores when it comes to simulations. Is this true?

Note: I think I have time until the beginning of next week to decide

Comment: Rendering memory is used on a per frame basis. Having a long animation should not affect it much

Comment: Read also:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47598/should-i-buy-a-better-cpu-or-gpu and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48887/a-powerful-graphics-card-or-cloud-render-farm-which-is-more-effective/48892#48892

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GPU will run out of memory as soon as your scene is larger than the available memory. When you hit render, all your geometry and your textures will be loaded.
You can try some of your scenes and have a look at the top left corner of the window. There you'll see the required amount of memory.

Also, have a look at this: [Blender Benchmarks](http://download.blender.org/institute/benchmark/latest_snapshot.html)

There you can see how different Hardware (including 1080Ti) performs in various scenes.

Comment: Very useful. I thought it was much faster then an 1800x. But judging by my heaviest scene, 11 gb is not totally safe.